# Strapi admin panel can't get loaded on vps server

Tags: authentication, server, hash, strapi

I have problem with running my strapi admin panel on adress /admin. I use Ubuntu.

Server is set correctly, but I think authentication can't be handled. I have error in console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest').
I think it is due to insecure address, but how to fix that, because it should work.
Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error, but it was resolved after I upgraded the Strapi version to 4.13.1.

- Update your strapi version
- Use node version 18.17.1